# composer minimum stabilit conflict

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php

```
"repositories": [  
    {  
        "type": "vcs",  
        "url": "https://github.com/maxim-chugaev/form"  
    },
    {  
        "type": "vcs",  
        "url": "https://github.com/maxim-chugaev/bootforms"  
    }  
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "adamwathan/bootforms": "dev-master@dev",
    "watson/bootstrap-form": "^1.1",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2.0",
    "adamwathan/form": "dev-master@dev"
},
```

In `adamwathan/bootform@master` :

```
"repositories": [  
    {  
        "type": "vcs",  
        "url": "https://github.com/maxim-chugaev/form"  
    }  
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "adamwathan/form": "dev-master@dev"
},
```

But i have:

> - adamwathan/bootforms dev-master requires adamwathan/form ^0.8.11 -> satisfiable by adamwathan/form[v0.8.11, v0.8.12] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Why? Where does the composer take the version `^0.8.11 of` the package adamwathan/form?